# Regex and / and " in Scala/Gatling

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

I have a html response and want to save a token (bid_kid) below

```
<head>
    <meta name="WT.cg_n" content="Loginsider">
    <meta name="DCSext.loginPage" content="Logg inn - Din side">
    <meta content="no" http-equiv="Content-Language">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/xmlhttp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_public/gjeff/css/gjeff.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_public/gjeff/js/gjeff.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script language="JavaScript" src="javascript/dummy_bid20_xxx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="bid_kid" content="17RA18B5YKIU6A89PIZ6ED0ZYRV1KH">
    <meta name="ajaxurl" content="../no/0/ajax/loginpage-bankid">
    <script src="javascript/init_bid_helper_proto.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>

    <title>Logg inn - here</title>
</head>
```

However the check I am running is appearing to be malformated in IntelliJ like this (adds two \):

```
.check(regex("content=\\\"(?<bid_kid>[0-9A-Z]*)\\\"").find.saveAs("token"))
```

Do I need to "wrap" the regex experssion in some mather to make this work in Gatling/Scala?

The regex works using a regex tester and it is like this:

```
content=\"(?<bid_kid>[0-9A-Z]*)\"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I get an error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: named capturing group is missing trailing '>' near index 15
content="(?<bid_kid>[0-9A-Z]*)"

Comment: using what you suggest makes intellij "go orange" on the \ in \". .check(regex("content=\"(?<bid_kid>[0-9A-Z]*)\"").find.saveAs("bidkid"))

Comment: You still do not need to escape `"` whatever you are told by IntelliJ, but as per your comment, the only problem is that you should remove `_` from the group name. Change `bid_kid` to `bidkid`, or just replace the named capturing group with a simple  numbered one, i.e. `regex("content=\"([0-9A-Z]*)\"")`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029657/scala-regex-named-capturing-groups/3029730#3029730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acc. to the [Java regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname), the named group syntax does not allow underscores:

> A capturing group can also be assigned a "name", a named-capturing group, and then be back-referenced later by the "name". Group names are composed of the following characters. The first character must be a letter.
>
> - The uppercase letters 'A' through 'Z' ('\u0041' through '\u005a'),
> - The lowercase letters 'a' through 'z' ('\u0061' through '\u007a'),
> - The digits '0' through '9' ('\u0030' through '\u0039'),

Thus, you should change your code to

```
.check(regex("content=\\\"(?<bidkid>[0-9A-Z]*)\\\"").find.saveAs("token"))
```