# How best to access the number of capturing groups in a Pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the number of capturing groups in an instance of `Pattern`.  I know method `Matcher.groupCount()` exists, but it requires a valid input string.

Is there a way to access the number of capturing groups **without** an instance of `Matcher`?

My current hack uses reflection to access the package-private field `Pattern.capturingGroupCount`, but this is terrible for many reasons.

```
Field f = Pattern.class.getDeclaredField("capturingGroupCount");
int capturingGroupCount = (int) f.get(pattern);
```

I use Java 9+, so it is not possible -- that I know -- to create a helper method in package `java.util.regex` to access package-private field `capturingGroupCount`.  (The Java compiler complains that package `java.util.regex` is already defined in module `java.base`.)

Final thought / opinion: I am surprised the Java API does not expose this member, e.g., `int capturingGroupCount()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying capture groups in a Regex Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589643/identifying-capture-groups-in-a-regex-pattern)

Comment: @Booboo: Yes, but indirectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know method `Matcher.groupCount()` exists, but it requires a valid input string.

No, it doesn't.

The following has been tested on Java 7 and Java 13:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(x)y(z)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");
System.out.println(m.groupCount()); // prints: 2
```

As you can see, you don't even have to call `find()` or `matches()` first, but you do have to create the `Matcher` instance.

> Is there a way to access the number of capturing groups without an instance of `Matcher`?

Not in plain Java, i.e. without using reflection.