# Java Regex won't match, any explanations?

Tags: java, regex

The regex `String` :

```
"[Ff][uU][Nn][Cc] "
```

Matches input:

```
"fUnC "
```

But not:

```
"func across( a, b )"
```

And I don't understand *why...*

I'm testing my expressions here:
http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

I figured out that I (dumbly) needed my regex to be `"[Ff][uU][Nn][Cc] .*"` for a match.

SOLVED:  Don't use the convenience method `Pattern.Matches(regex, input)` if you are looking for what amounts to a submatch.  You should use the `Matcher.find()` method instead.

Comment: I'm not trying to match the whole string, just testing that the symbol "func " can be detected in the string.

Comment: Why not use an option to make regexes case insensitive?

Comment: That would be cleaner, but that didn't work.  Using the test site (and my own code) the only way to score a match was with `.*` at the end.

Comment: Java's `Pattern.Matches(regex, input)` apparently tries to match only the entire string.  Also, you can't set flags when using Pattern.Matches, so I didn't bother with case-insensitive.

Comment: are you using Matcher.matches, or Matcher.find?

Comment: I was using the convenience method `Pattern.Matches(regex, input)` which uses the matches.  I learned through this that Matches goes for the whole line, find looks for substrings.  Not how I'm used to doing things, but it works now...

Comment: As you see, Java’s `matches` method is rather more of an **inconvenience method** than a convenience one. :) You’re hardly the first one to get tripped up by Java’s bizarre redefinition of the word *matches.* There are [plenty of other gotchas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767627/java-regex-helper/5771326#5771326), too. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use the regex tester you link to, I see that your regex works with find(), but not with matches().  This is what I would expect -- find() just looks for a regex hit within the target string, while matches() always tries to match the entire string.

Comment: No way to learn that like the hard way, lol.  I'll alter the code.

Answer (score 0):

"[Ff][uU][Nn][Cc].*"  may help...

Comment: It should match without the `.*`, since `func ` matches the pattern.

Comment: My mistake was in forgetting that matches are lazy. Sure, I might match part of the string, but not all of it.  I have it working now...

Comment: Yes. But 'func across...' doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It can be.... it's working fine. But your strings in there and you'll see MATCHES is false, but replaceFirst and ReplaceAll work fine.

If you want MATCHES to be true

add a * at the end

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried using the regex tester, ignoring case? There should be a way to turn on case insensitivity in the Java regex matcher.

Comment: Not when using the convenience method `Pattern.Matches(regex, input)`.  You only can use those flags when doing manual manipulation.