# Regular expression for Multi Bytes string

Tags: java, regex

What could be the regular expression to detect a multi byte string.

For example here is the expression to detect a string in english

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z/]");
```

Similarly I want a pattern which has multi bytes like

> コメント_1050_固-減価償却費

Comment: AFAIK, in Java UCS-2 is used, i.e. all strings are multibyte. You may input symbols with char `code > 127` just as Latin ones in their normal form: `ン` as well as in the following form: `\u30FC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Unicode Support in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html)

I think basically you want the Unicode property `\p{L}`. This would match any code point that has the property "letter".

So your regex could look like this

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}/]");
```

I just replaced the character ranges `a-zA-Z` with `\p{L}`

---

Since Java 7 you could also use `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

> Enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes.

That would turn the predefined `\w` into the Unicode version, means it would match all Unicode letters and digits (and string connecting characters like _)

So to match your string `コメント_1050_固-減価償却費`, you could use

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^\\w+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

This would match any string consisting of letters, digits and _

See [here for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)

and here on [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) an overview over the Unicode scripts, properties and blocks.

[See here a famous answer from tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771326/626273) about the caveats of regex in Java, including an updated what has changed with Java 7 (or will be in Java 8)

Comment: But I tried following codes with JRE 8, it still wrong:
String input = "";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\u2A775]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
  System.out.println("In Range :" + p.matcher(input).find());

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect whether you have a multi-byte strings you cna look at the length

```
if (text.length() != text.getBytes(encoding).length)
```

This will detect that a multi-byte character has been used for any encoding.

Comment: Its not as fast as some of the other suggestions, but its more general and you can be sure what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, Java regular expressions work on Strings, not arrays of bytes - characters are represented as abstract "character" entities, not as bytes in some specific encoding. This is not completely true since the `char` type only contains characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane and Unicode chars from outside this range are represented as two `char` values each, but nonetheless "multibyte" is relative and depends on the encoding.

If what you need is "multibyte in UTF-8", then note that only characters with values 0-127 are single-byte in this encoding. So, the easiest way to check would be to use a loop and check each character - if it's greater than 127, it's more than one byte in UTF-8.

If you insist on using a regex, you could probably use the character range operator in the regex like this: `[\u0080-\uFFFF]` (haven't checked and `\uFFFF` is not really a character but I think the regex engine should accept it).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Unicode` for elements which are not in the English language. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) link should provide you with some information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice introduction to UniCode regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).