# Regular Expression: ReplaceAllIn returns a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when generating UTF-8

Tags: regex, scala, unicode, utf-8

I want to replace all occurrences of a regular expression of type "\uXXXX" where "XXXX" is an 
 hexadecimal number representing a Unicode character to the corresponding character.

I tried the following Scala code:

```
def unscape(s : String) : String = {
 val rex = """\\u([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])""".r
 rex.replaceAllIn(s,m => {
     hex2str(m.group(1))
   }
}

def hex2str(s:String): String = {
  Integer.parseInt(s,16).toChar.toString  
}
```

If I try, for example:

```
unscape("Hi\\u0024, \\u0024")
```

it gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008974/strange-java-unicode-regular-expression-stringindexoutofboundsexception), it seems that there could be a bug in Java's treatment of Unicode characters. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to tweak the accepted answer:

```
  def unscape3(s: String): String = {
    val rex = """\\u(\p{XDigit}{4})""".r
    rex.replaceAllIn(s, m => Regex quoteReplacement hex2str(m group 1))
  }

  Console println unscape3("""Hi\u0024, \u0024""")
```

Note that the character class is correct and you don't have to be aware of what needs escaping when using `quoteReplacement`.

(Maybe more efficient than scanning the replacement text multiple times.)

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
def unscape(s: String): String = {
    val rex = """\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})""".r
    rex.replaceAllIn(s, m => {
        hex2str(m.group(1))
            .replaceAllLiterally("\\", "\\\\")
            .replaceAllLiterally("$", "\\$")
    })
}
```

According to [Matcher.appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) which is iternally used by `replaceAllIn`:

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

Comment: But it throws on `"\\u004H"`. You meant A-F. See other answer.

Comment: OK, right...I noticed later because it raised again the exception...thanks also :)