# why does \B works but not \b

Tags: java, javascript, .net, regex

Wanted to match a **word** that ends with `#` like

hi **hello#**  **world#**

I tried to use boundary

```
\b\w+#\b
```

and it doesn't match.I thought `\b` is a non word boundary but it doesn't seem so from this case

---

Surprisingly

```
\b\w+#\B
```

matches!

So why does `\B` works here and not `\b`!Also why doesn't `\b` work in this case!

---

**NOTE:**
Yes we can use `\b\w+#(?=\s|$)` but I want to know why `\B` works in this case!

Comment: read [http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: @Anirudh I think that's because of the space after the first `#`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes indeed and that space should have been matched by `\b`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the space... everything to do with the `#`.

Comment: @AymanSafadi It does have something to do with the space, because the pattern does match the string `hi hello#world#`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Definition of word boundary `\b`

Defining word boundary in word is imprecise. Let me define the word boundary with *look-ahead*, *look-behind*, and short-hand word character class `\w`.

A word boundary `\b` is equivalent to:

```
(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

Which means:

- Right ahead, there is (at least) a character that is a word character, **and** right behind, we cannot find a word character (either the character is not a word character, or it is the start of the string).

  **OR**
- Right behind, there is (at least) a character that is a word character, **and** right ahead, we cannot find a word character (either the character is not a word character, or it is the end of the string).

(Note how similar this is to the expansion of XOR into conjunction and disjunction)

A non-word boundary `\B` is equivalent to:

```
(?:(?<!\w)(?!\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\w))
```

Which means:

- Right ahead and right behind, we cannot find any word character. Note that empty string is consider a non-word boundary under this definition.

  **OR**
- Right ahead and right behind, both sides are word characters. Note that this branch requires 2 characters, i.e. cannot occur at the beginning or the end of a non-empty string.

(Note how similar this is to the expansion of XNOR into conjunction and disjunction).

### Definition of word character `\w`

Since the definition of `\b` and `\B` depends on definition of `\w`<sup>1</sup>, you need to consult the specific documentation to know exactly what `\w` matches.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Most of the regex flavors define `\b` based on `\w`. Well, [except for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767627/java-regex-helper/5771326#5771326) <sup>[Point 9]</sup>, where in default mode, `\w` is ASCII-only and `\b` is partially Unicode-aware.</sup>

- In [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), it would be `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in default mode.
- In [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter), `\w` by default would match `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\P{Lm}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`, and it will have the same behaviour as JavaScript if [ECMAScript option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) is specified. In the [list of characters in Pc category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm), you only have to know that space (ASCII 32) is not included.

### Answer to the question

With the definition above, answering the question becomes easy:

```
"hi hello# world#"
```

In `hello#`, after `#` is space ([U+0020, in Zs category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)), which is not a word character, and `#` is not a word character itself ([in Unicode, it is in Po category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0023/index.htm)). Therefore, `\B` can match here. The branch `(?<!\w)(?!\w)` is used in this case.

In `world#`, after `#` is end of string. Since `#` is not a word character, and we cannot find any word character ahead (there is nothing there), `\B` can match the empty string just after `#`. The branch `(?<!\w)(?!\w)` is also used in this case.

### Addendum

Alan Moore gives quite a good summary in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623181/why-does-b-works-but-not-b/16624542?noredirect=1#comment23906040_16624542):

> I think the key point to remember is that regexes can't read. That is, they don't deal in words, only in characters. When we say `\b` matches the beginning or end of a word, we don't mean it identifies a word and then seeks out its endpoints, like a human would. All it can see is the character *before* the current position and the character *after* the current position. Thus, `\b` only indicates that the current position *could* be a word boundary. It's up to you to make sure the characters on either side what they should be.

Comment: I think the key point to remember is that regexes can't read. That is, they don't deal in words, only in characters.  When we say `\b` matches the beginning or end of a word, we don't mean it identifies a word and then seeks out its endpoints, like a human would.  All it can see is the character *before* the current position and the character *after* the current position.  Thus, `\b` only indicates that the current position *could* be a word boundary.  It's up to you to make sure the characters on either side what they should be.

Answer (score 5):

The pound `#` symbol is not considered a "word boundary".

`\b\w+#\b` doesn't work because `w+#` is not considered a word, therefore it will not match `world#`.
`\b\w+6\b` on the other hand is, therefore it *will* match `world6`.

"Word Characters" are defined by: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

> Simply put: `\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".
>   
> — http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: yes indeed..but `\b.+?\b` seems to match any word containing non word character too

Comment: So `\b` is not a character that the RegEx matches, it is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). In other words your RegEx isn't matching word or non-word characters, it's matching `w+#` in your first example and `.+?` (anything) in your second. You're using the `\b` anchor to describe the "surroundings" of your match.

Comment: `The pound # symbol is not considered a "word boundary".` Word boundary is not defined by a single character. It is defined by 2 characters. `"Word Characters" are defined by: [A-Za-z0-9_].` Depends on which language you are using. If we are talking about .NET, then it will include Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` and the space are both non-word characters, so the invisible boundary between them is not a word boundary. Therefore `\b` will not match it and `\B` will match it.