# jMeter RegEx JSON response

Tags: regex, jmeter

I've read a few tutorials on jMeter RegEx extraction but it's not working. I'm using jMeter 2.7.

I have this JSON:

```
{"address":{"id":26,"user_id":1,"genre":"billing","first_name":"testFN1","last_name":"testLN1","company":null,"street1":null,"street2":null,"city":null,"state":"DC","zip":null,"country":null,"country_iso2":null,"phone1":"32432424322","phone2":null}}
```

and this RegEx Extractor: "id":(.+?), here's the screenshot of jMeter

[image]

For the extraction, I get `$new_address_id` = **2**, instead of **26**. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 6/26/2012**:

Thanks Cylian for your suggestion. It is very helpful. I ended up changing it to: `"id":(\d+)`.

I also did a find a replace in the JMX file for

```
<stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&quot;id&quot;:(.+?,)</stringProp>
```

and replace with

```
<stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&quot;id&quot;:(\d+)</stringProp>
```

Which made the fix quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at :

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/

This section (JSON utils (JSON Path Assertion, JSON Path Extractor, JSON Formatter)) in particular for this case. These are set of jmeter tools developed in my company, they're very useful.

Let's take your case as example. The test case looks like this :

[image]

So dummy sample returns response, just like the one you specified :

```
{"address":{"id":26,"user_id":1,"genre":"billing","first_name":"testFN1","last_name":"testLN1","company":null,"street1":null,"street2":null,"city":null,"state":"DC","zip":null,"country":null,"country_iso2":null,"phone1":"32432424322","phone2":null}}
```

JSON extraction is very simple :

```
$.address.id
```

And there you go no need for fancy regexes. Result is 26 (that is what I see in debug sampler).

Update from question in comments :

If you were to have list of values i.e. :

```
{"address":[{"id":26,"user_id":1,"genre":"billing","first_name":"testFN1","last_name":"testLN1","company":null,"street1":null,"street2":null,"city":null,"state":"DC","zip":null,"country":null,"country_iso2":null,"phone1":"32432424322","phone2":null}, {"id":6,"user_id":1,"genre":"billing","first_name":"testFN1","last_name":"testLN1","company":null,"street1":null,"street2":null,"city":null,"state":"DC","zip":null,"country":null,"country_iso2":null,"phone1":"32432424322","phone2":null}]}
```

List with 2 address-es , 1 has id 26 and another one 6. The Json Path `$.address.id` should return both of these ids. I just saw sampler source code and it's not possible to get the count however you can do it by adding another post processor to your sample i.e `BSF Sampler` and by adding this code :

```
vars.put("ADDRESS_COUNT", "${__javaScript('${add}'.split('\,').length,)}".toString());
```

Where `${add}` is any variable where you stored results of `$.address.id`.

Comment: ant, this is very interesting. However, for some reason, I wasn't able to get mvn to compile the file. Is there a JAR file that can be downloaded without compiling?

Comment: @Dean you're probably using maven 2 to build the project. You should use maven 3, sorry for not mentioning that in the github page I'll change that

Comment: @Dean were you able to build ?

Comment: Hi ant, sorry, I didn't get a chance to build after the regex worked. I'll look into it when I'm doing some more complex checks

Comment: Hi ant, I got OS X Lion and use RailsInstaller. It built it very easily. I like the components. However, I couldn't find more info regarding the various components here: http://www.atlantbh.com/jmeter-components/. For example, there's nothing on the JSON extraction component.

Comment: @Dean sorry dean I do not have anymore details but the ones you found on that website, you can take a look at the source codes https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components/ if you really want to know what's going on

Comment: Hi ant, I'm trying to extra the last occurrence of "id" in an array, or count the number of items in array for assertion, any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Dean please see my update, I'm sure that authors can/will/plan to make updates to those components. Please contact them if you have further ideas this was just from the top of my head and might not be the best way to get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 14):

You are using `.+?` which means:

- `.` - Match any single character that is not a line break character(default, may be changed using `s` flag)
- `+` - Match preceding  character between one and unlimited times
- `?` - As few times as possible (lazy)

So, while it is going to match `"id":26` the pattern matches `.+?` as `2` only instead of `26`.

To fix this issue you try something better than this:

```
  ("id":\d+)\b
```

means

```
// ("id":\d+)\b
// 
// Options: case insensitive
// 
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «("id":\d+)»
//    Match the characters “"id":” literally «"id":»
//    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

***or***

```
  ("id":[^,:]+)\b
```

means

```
// ("id":[^,:]+)\b
// 
// Options: case insensitive
// 
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «("id":[^,:]+)»
//    Match the characters “"id":” literally «"id":»
//    Match a single character NOT present in the list “,:” «[^,:]+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

*or*

```
("id":\S+)\b
```

***means***

```
// ("id":\S+)\b
// 
// Options: case insensitive
// 
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «("id":\S+)»
//    Match the characters “"id":” literally «"id":»
//    Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character” «\S+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to select JSON response in jmeter it is to do something like (?m) "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/idSpaceStore",\s* "name": "folder_for_testing-1372432881900",

(?m) - means start treat regexp as multi line oriented
(\s*) - means any characters