# need regular expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation

```
{"string":"{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"2c9180834e532f54014e6759d2ac004b\",\"unitName\":\"Actual11\",\"owner\":\"Nikolus\",\"description\":\"performance\",\"nofChairs\":0,\"nofBeds\":0,\"nofApptStartWithInHour\":0,\"nofApptDischargeWithInHour\":0,\"modifiedDateTime\":\"Jul 7, 2015 12:10:17
```

this is my response. this id will be used in next scripts. plz help me

Comment: Please check [jMeter RegEx JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060483/jmeter-regex-json-response). I guess it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
\{"string":"\{\\"data\\":\[\{\\"id\\":\\"(\w+)\\",
```

This will work only if your response data is as you have given. I think some \ are extra like `{\"data\":[{\"id\"`. This should be like, `{"data":[{"id"`. In such case,

```
\{"string":"\{"data":\[\{"id":"(\w+)",
```

This should be enough. Next time show your efforts first.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'd better use any JSON decoder instead?

**UPD**

```
/{"string":"{\\"data\\":\[{\\"id\\":\\"([a-f0-9]+)\\".*/
```

I don't actually know whether order and names of your keys remains the same.

Comment: this should be posted as comment instead.

Comment: @Raptor I provided a RegEx that answers the question.