# How to parse JSON data?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to find all `id` values where `available":true`:

*Formated for better readability:*

```
{
   "KEN":[
      {
         "name":"Mombasa",
         "id":"MBA",
         "available":false,
         "group":[

         ],
         "children":[

         ],
         "countryName":"Kenya",
         "countryCode":"KEN",
         "synonym":""
      }
   ],
   ...
}
```

*Actual JSON string*

```
{"KEN":[{"name":"Mombasa","id":"MBA","available":false,"group":[],"children":[],"countryName":"Kenya","countryCode":"KEN","synonym":""}],...
```

I have tried to parse it with the following regular expression

```
\{"name":".+?","id":"(.+?)","available":true,.+?,"synonym":""\}
```

but its not working.

I am using Regular Jmeter.

Comment: Install JSON plugins to work with JSON data in JMeter. Avoid working on JSON with regex

Comment: Example of JSONPathExtractor plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060483/jmeter-regex-json-response/11204000#11204000

Comment: Please specify what not working means for you: error | no results | too much results? Just as a hint I'd use start and end line chars too (`^`, `$`). Also lines starting with "name:" end with "group:", not "synonym:", you mix "name:" and "CountryName:" lines

Comment: Your regex looks fine, you might find https://regex101.com/ useful, but you should not use regex for parsing JSON.

Comment: when I used \{"name":".+?","id":"(.+?)","available":true,.+?,"synonym":""\} following this got selected

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Relevant JSONPath query will look somehow like

```
.KEN.[?(@.available=='false')].id
```

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for instructions on plugin setup and some form of JSONPath language reference.