# Extracting data from JSON response in JMeter

Tags: regex, json, response, jmeter

I am trying to create a JMeter script for an online insurance application that creates repair bookings for automotive claims. One of the responses to this application returns a JSON object that has the time slots available and unavailable to book repair jobs. An example of the JSON is below.

```
{
    "7": {
        "45": 1,
        "30": 1
    },
    "8": {
        "45": 1,
        "30": 0,
        "15": 1,
        "00": 0
    },
    "9": {
        "45": 1,
        "30": 1,
        "15": 1,
        "00": 1
    },
    "10": {
        "45": 0,
        "30": 1,
        "15": 1,
        "00": 1
    }
}
```

This shows the hours 7am, 8am, 9am and 10am. With timeslots 7:45, 7:30, 7:00 etc. A 1 against the minute slot indicates that this slot is free. So the first free slot is 7:45.

How can I use a regular expression to extract the first free slot?

I came up with this regex to get the hour slot... `"(\d{1})":{"\d{2}":1`, but can't work out how to accurately extract the minute slot.

I'm wondering whether it would be easier to do this using a BSF Postprocessor and some javascript. Unfortunately my scripting skills are poor.

Can anyone offer me any help in how to extract this info using a regex or possibly using a BSF post processor?

Comment: what exactly do you want to extract? what does " the first free slot". Can you give sample output?

Answer (score 1):

More powerful - as well as more complicated - way will be implementing JSON response processing using BeanShell scripting (~ java) + any json-processing library ([json-rpc-1.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/metaparadigm/json-rpc/1.0/json-rpc-1.0.jar) e.g.).

Look into the links below for details/samples/code:

- [Pulling multiple values from JSON response using RegEx Extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125896/pulling-multiple-values-from-json-response-using-regex-extractor)
- [JSON in JMeter](http://theworkaholic.blogspot.com/2012/05/json-in-jmeter.html)
- [Processing JSON Responses with Jmeter and the BSF Post Processor](http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=500)

Comment: I want to extract the first free slot so 7:45. The sample output is in my original post but here it is again...{"7":{"45":1,"30":1},"8":{"45":1,"30":1,"15":1,"00":1},"9":{"45":1,"30":1,"15":0,"00":1},"10":{"45":1,"30":1,"15":1,"00":1}}.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you're trying to find just the first two number occurrences you can use something like this:

```
(\w+)(?:[\D]*)(\w*)
```

I posted the expression on [regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/3gnc) so you can test various input JSONs.