# Converting C# regular expression to Java

Tags: c#, java, regex

This regular expression in C# is giving me error in java:

```
"<input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="(?<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)">"
```

Error:

```
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 60
<input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="(?<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)">
```

What would be the equivalent expression in Java?

Comment: First of all you should not use regex to parse HTML, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not to see why. Secondly, what error are you getting? And thirdly, Java, by default, seems to add the ^ and $ anchors to your regex, so you will have to cater for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This i'm guessing. I changed ' to " and escaped any "

```
"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"GALX\" value=\"(?<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\">"
```

**Edit** :: And for the named grouping of "galx" only java 7 supports this

[Regex Named Groups in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java)

Comment: sorry the ' was actually ". mistakenly changed it here

Comment: @UzairFarooq I believe this answers your question however

Comment: no...that's not the answer, I'm still getting the runtime error

Comment: @UzairFarooq Like i said, are you using java 1.7 or not

Comment: @ AlanFoster Yes you are right, I changed it to this and it works fine:
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"GALX\" value=\"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\">"
Thanks