# Conversion of C#.Net Regex to Java Regex Pattern

Tags: c#, java, regex

I'm not a pro in Regex, therefore I'm having a difficulty translating this regex pattern to Java.

I believe it would be an easy task to a guy which is familiar enough with Regex.
I have seen similar topics, however - each topic is relevant for a specific regex pattern...

**The Pattern is:**

```
@"\<meta name=""title"" content=""(?<title>.*)""\>"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing interesting I see in there is the double-quotes. Remove the `@` at the front, un-double the quotes and escape them instead (with a backslash).

Comment: I did so. I didn't just copy-paste it to Java... I removed the '@' and changed the special characters to \* (e.g. \" instead of "" and \\ instead of \), and yet I got an exception that this is not a valid Regex Pattern

Comment: It's probably the named capture. I cant find any straight answer on if Java supports them. Try taking it out. Replace `(?<title>.*)` with just `(.*)` (Edit: Actually, apparently Java7 does but not prior http://stackoverflow.com/a/415635/65387)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want slashes in front of the openning and closing angle-brackets, use this (escaped for Java):

```
"\\\\<meta name=\"title\" content=\"(.*)\"\\\\>"
```

Without them, use this:

```
"<meta name=\"title\" content=\"(.*)\">"
```

[Tested here](http://fiddle.re/ryjn) using the unescaped version:

```
<meta name="title" content="(.*)">
```

Comment: I have tried it, and got an exception. just to be sure, I have tested it on http://regex.powertoy.org/ as-well, and got a negative result.