# Looking for solution [Java, Regex?]

Tags: java, regex

I have the following usecase and looking for the right solution.

We are reading a csv file and populating a POJO.One column in from the file could map to multiple fields in the POJO.

eg:

```
Class Test {

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;
......
other fields
---
getter methods
.....
 setter methods 
}
```

Let us say value of column XXXX from file is 123_TEST_34_THJ

the field1 value is 123
field2 value is 34
filed3 value THJ

I can do this in the Java code, but I am looking a solution to split this dynamically. Let us say the value of XXXX is now changed to 124_34_THJ, I want my code to work just with a configuration change. What would be a better solution? Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: So you want to split `XXXX` at `_` and then filter away `TEST`?

Comment: The question is not clear - what are the possible rules for mapping value to object?

Comment: Making something [*too configurable*](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Enterprise-User-Agent.aspx) can be almost as bad as not configurable enough. Unless this *requires* said flexibility, just write the code (arguably business logic) as part of the actual program. (Keeping in mind the basic rules for separation of concerns and good coding practices.)

Comment: Why did you skip `TEST` as a field value? Is that the only term to skip? Was skipping `TEST` an oversight?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with named captures:

```
(?<field1>\d+)_\w+_(?<field2>\d+)_(?<field3>\w+)
```

Then next week it might be...

```
(?<field2>\d+)_(?<field7>\w+)_(?<field1>\d+)_(?<field3>\w+)
```

More info on your choices for regex libraries with named captures at [Regex Named Groups in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java)

Comment: Note: Named groups is only supported in java 7

Comment: Yeah, that's pointed out in the link, along with libraries for earlier versions of Java.