# Extract numbers and names from string

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to extract names and numbers from a string in java.
Examples: input -> output

> 1234 -> numbers: [1234], names: []
>
> 1234,34,234 -> numbers: [1234, 34, 234], names: []
>
> 12,foo,123 -> numbers: [12, 123], names: [foo]
>
> foo3,1234,4bar,12,12foo34 -> numbers: [1234, 12], names: [foo3, 4bar, 12foo34]
>
> foo,bar -> -> numbers: [], names: [foo, bar]

I came up with `[^,]+(,?!,+)*` which match all parts of the string, but i dont know how to match only numbers or names (names can contain number - as in example).
Thanks

Comment: You could just use OR and groups: `(\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB0iS6)

Comment: Also named groups may be interesting, since I'm not a java dev, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/415635/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a regex-only solution:

```
(?:(\d+)|([^,]+))(?=,|$)
```

The first group `(\d+)` captures numbers, the second group `([^,]+)` captures the rest. A group must be followed by a comma or the end of line `(?=,|$)`.

A quick demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+)|([^,]+))(?=,|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo3,1234,4bar,12,12foo34");

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) != null 
        ? "Number: " + m.group(1)  
        : "Non-Number: " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Non-Number: foo3
Number: 1234
Non-Number: 4bar
Number: 12
Non-Number: 12foo34
```

Comment: Why not just `\d+|[^,]+`? No need for a capturing group then, a matcher's `.group()` will return the needed value

Comment: you forgot to exclude whitespaces :p

Comment: @fge: Because then, you know whether a match was a number or a non-number

Comment: @HamZa: The OP had no whitespaces in their example

Comment: @LukasEder you know in BOTH cases, see my answer

Comment: @fge: Point taken. But mine is a regex-only solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
sc.useDelimiter(",");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int readInt = sc.nextInt();
        // do something with the int
    } else {
        String readString = sc.next();
        // do something with the String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
        String a = "abc,123,abs12,12ab";
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        String ar[] = (a.split(","));
        for (String string : ar) {
            try{
                Long.parseLong(string);
                numbers.add(string);
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                letters.add(string);
            }
        }
```

Above solution handles the cases where integer digit can be at any location in the string. Not only at the beginning or at the end.