# Configurable String parser similar to Date parsers

Tags: java, parsing, pattern-matching

I'm wondering if there is a java library, which can parse strings in a similar manner as date parsers. For example with the `SimpleDateFormat` class it is possible to define a pattern (`yyMMddHHmmssZ`) to parse a String (`010704120856-0700`) for getting the date. Instead of parsing dates I would like to parse arbitary numbers.

For example I would like to be able to parse:

```
String:  X0759502.CSV
Pattern: DSSIYYMM.CSV   
   X -> Data version:
         'X' GOES X-ray
         'M' GOES Magnetometer
         'P' GOES Electrons, Protons & Alpha particles.
   07 -> GOES-7, 91 = SMS-1, 92=SMS-2, etc.
    3 -> 3-second values
   YY -> year
   MM -> month
```

And then for example getting a hashmap, where I can use the key word (ex. YY) to get the extracted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With java it is possible to use Regex's [Named Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java). With that approache it is possible to achieve something similar to a `SimpleDateFormat` parser.

To parse the provided example (`X0759502.CSV`), this regex was used:

```
x(?<satellite>\\d{2})(?<interval>\\d)(?<year>\\d{2})(?<month>\\d{2}).csv$
```

With the `matcher.group("satellite")` is used to get the `07`.

Answer (score 1):

it appears that you want regular expression parsing (aka regex).
Check out [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
The links are to the java 7 API,
but both classes have been around since java 1.5 (or before).