# Replace the opening and closing string, while keeping the enclosed value?

Tags: java, regex

```
String value="==Hello==";
```

For the above string, I have to replace the "==" tags as `<Heading>Hello</Heading>`. I have tried doing it like this:

```
value = value.replaceAll("(?s)\\=\\=.","<heading>");
value = value.replaceAll(".\\=\\=(?s)","</heading>");
```

However, my original dataset is huge, with lots of strings like this to be replaced. Can the above be performed in a single statement, giving preference to performance?

The regex should not affect strings of form, `===<value>===`, where value is any string of characters[a-z,A-Z].

Comment: `replaceAll("===([^=]+)===", "<Heading>$1</Heading>")`

Comment: @darth can input look like `==foo=bar==`? If yes what should be result? Or `==a==b==c==`?

Comment: What does "solution't" mean?

Comment: The input will be of the form, "==<value>==", or ===<value>===

Comment: To clarify your question please use [edit] option. Don't make people search for crucial info in comments. Also what exactly `<value>` represent? Can it for instance contain another nested `==<abc>==`? If yes how should it be handled?

Comment: No, it can only contain strings,[a-z,A-Z]

Comment: So for now it looks like you want to replace `==value==` but not `===value===`. In other words you want to replace two continuous equation marks but not three. In that case you may be looking for `value = value.replaceAll("(?<!=)==([a-zA-Z])==(?!=)","<heading>$1</heading>");` `(?<!subexpression)` ensures that `subexpression` (here `=`) doesn't appear *before* match, similarly `(?!subexpression)` that `subexpression` (here `=`) doesn't appear *after* match. For more info read about "regex lookaround".

Comment: Anyway since your input also contains `===<value>===` something tells me you will want to also replace these but with different tags. If that is true then your question is example of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where for real problem there may be better solution than the problem you described.

Comment: If I use replaceAll("===([^=]+)===", "<subheading>$1</subheading>"); and then replaceAll("==([^=]+)==", "<heading>$1</heading>"), the problem is solved. I just need to solve bigger regex (===), before trying to solve for (==). Thank you for your help. Do you think I should delete this question due to bad quality?

Comment: I am not sure. In your solution you need to iterate over string twice, once searching for `===` then second for `==`. You could do it in one iteration with little help of `Matcher#appendReplacement` and `Matcher#appendTail`. Also I am saying this because I am making some assumptions about how your input is formatted so solution which I am thinking about may not work if there is something I didn't know about input. Anyway give me a minute, I will post my idea as answer and you can decide if it was what you ware looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid iterating over string many times to first replace `===abc===` and then `==def==` we can iterate over it once and thanks to `Matehr#appendReplacement` and `Matcher#appendTail` dynamically decide how to replace found match (based on amount of `=`).

Regex which can search find both described cases can look like: `(={2,3})([a-z]+)\1` but to make it more usable lets use [named groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java) `(?<name>subregex)` and also instead of `[a-z]` use more general `[^=]+`.

This will give us

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<eqAmount>={2,3})(?<value>[^=]*)\\k<eqAmount>");
```

Group named `eqAmount` will hold `==` or `===`. `\\k<eqAmount>` is backreference to that group, which means regex expects to find it also `==` or `===` depending on what `eqAmount` already holds.

Now we need some mapping between `==` or `===` and replacements. To hold such mapping we can use

```
Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
replacements.put("===", "<subheading>${value}</subheading>");
replacements.put("==", "<heading>${value}</heading>");
```

`${value}` is reference to capturing group named `value` - here `(?<value>[^=]*)` so it will hold text between both `==` or `===`.

Now lets see how it works:

```
String input = "===foo=== ==bar== ==baz== ===bam===";

Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
replacements.put("===", "<subheading>${value}</subheading>");
replacements.put("==", "<heading>${value}</heading>");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<eqAmount>={2,3})(?<value>[^=]*)\\k<eqAmount>");

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacements.get(m.group("eqAmount")));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `<subheading>foo</subheading> <heading>bar</heading> <heading>baz</heading> <subheading>bam</subheading>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String value = "===Hello===";
        value = value.replaceAll("===([^=]+)===", "<Heading>$1</Heading>");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```