# Java Regex pattern using JDK 6

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex patterns and I want to build a regex which extracts below line from given content:

**Output**:

> https%253A%252F%252Fimages-na.ssl-imagesmazon.com%252Fimages%252FI%252F51tW%25252BoZNbJL.jpg

This didn't work with JDK1.6.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex =  "(?=<\\s*[^>]*\\s*id=\"pinterest\"\\s*[^>]*\\s*media%3D(?<media>.*.jpg))";
    final String string = "           \n"
         + "                        test\n"
         + "                            \n"
         + "                            <a id=\"pinterest\" data-height=\"570\" class=\"a-link-normal swf-social-site\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Pin it on Pinterest\" href=\"/gp/redirect.html/ref=cm_sw_cl_pi_dp_UUohAbSJXVH6B?_encoding=UTF8&amp;location=https%3A%2F%2Fpinterest.com%2Fpin%2Fcreate%2Fbutton%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.in%252Fdp%252FB00SIWUU2A%252Fref%253Dcm_sw_r_pi_dp_x_UUohAbSJXVH6B%26title%3DNegi%25203x3x3%2520Speed%2520Cube%2520Negi%26description%3DNegi%25203x3x3%2520Speed%2520Cube%2520Negi%2520https%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.in%252Fdp%252FB00SIWUU2A%252Fref%253Dcm_sw_r_pi_dp_x_UUohAbSJXVH6B%26media%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%252Fimages%252FI%252F41L8Ag%25252BfIZL.jpg&amp;token=49402B6CEDC244163E355CFF5E75B587C25D0183\"><i class=\"a-icon a-icon-share-pinterest\" aria-label=\"Pinterest\"><span class=\"a-icon-alt\">Pinterest</span></i></a><span class=\"a-letter-space\"></span>\n"
         + "                        \n"
         + "                ";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Getting Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 62
>   (?=<\s*[^>]*\s*id="pinterest"\s*[^>]*\s*media%3D(?.*.jpg))

Comment: How's it not working? what's the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I added error log to my question.

Comment: What is the second `?` in the regex at `(?<media>.*.jpg)` supposed to do on its own? That doesn't seem like correct syntax to me ...

Comment: @Neele Above code successfully working on java 8 but when I changed It to Java 6  then I got error.

Comment: @vikas Understood. The named group you're using with `(?<media>.*.jpg)` doesn't work in Java versions before 7. A question to work around that issue and possible solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java). Would that help you?