# how to understand regex pattern in the code example in java?

Tags: java, regex

The pattern is from the following Snippet.

```
private static Pattern specialDoubleRegex = Pattern.compile("((-)?infinityd?)|(nand?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I am a beginner. I am starting to use Pattern class to write my own regex. I saw this example in the [Java code example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=brut.apktool-master/brut.apktool.smali/smali/src/main/java/org/jf/smali/LiteralTools.java).I don’t completely understand them. Are we using special construct `(?<name>X)`?
According to [precious post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415580/regex-named-groups-in-java) and javase 7 docs, ?infinityd?) is not special construct here. what is `(-)?infinityd?` about?
Can I say that they are the pattern looks like `((X)?XY?)|(X?)` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are regular question marks that make the previous character or group optional.

- `(-)?infinityd?` matches "infinity" with an optional minus sign in front and an optional trailing "d". If the minus sign is present it is captured in group 2.

  ```
  infinity
  infinityd
  -infinity
  -infinityd
  ```
- `nand?` matches "nan" with an optional trailing "d".

  ```
  nan
  nand
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> Are we using special construct `(?<name>X)`?

To be clear, the *"Special constructs (named capturing and non-capturing)"* described in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for `Pattern` consist of a `(` immediately followed by a `?`.

In your example, the `?` symbols follow some other character.  As 
John explains, they are simple (greedy) quantifiers in each case.

Comment: Yes, I know he is right.  And so am I.  There is no named capturing group here *because* ... as I explained ... this is not the correct syntax for a "special construct".   Refer to the javadocs to understand the syntax.