# How to search with regex for fields containing whitespace-separated segments in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, regex-group, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

I have a document which contains a field called info_list which is basically a string with space separated 9 segments.

Mapping of the field is

```
"info_list": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

And the source document looks like

```
"_source": {
      "id": "1234",
      "date": "1614556800000",
      "info_list": [
        "1234 2D 5678 8765 5678 1111 2222 3333 1"
      ]
    }
```

The info list basically consists of 9 segments. For sake of question we can say that a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i are those 9 segments.

```
info_list = a+ ' ' + b+ ' ' + c +' ' + d+ ' ' e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g + ' ' + h + ' ' + i
```

Now suppose I want to search for c with value of 5678, the current implementation uses match_phrase query something like this

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "info_list": "5678"
    }
  }
}
```

The issue with above approach is that ,even though I wanted search result having c = 5678, now if any segment in info_list string has 5678 it will match that, resulting in wrong search result.

I tried using regex query something like

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : 
    { "fields" : ["info_list"],
      "query" : ".* .* 5678 .*"
      
    }
    
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.Should I change the mapping of the field ? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, since I am new to Elastic search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixing the regex

You've got to let the regex engine know **exactly how many** preceding groups there will be. On top of that, you'll need to use the [`.keyword` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type) because the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) that's applied on `text` fields by default will have split the original string by whitespace and converted each token to lowercase -- both of which should be prevented if you aim to work with capture groups.

Having said that, here's a working [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html):

```json
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "info_list.keyword": "( ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2} 5678 .*"
    }
  }
}
```

### Extracting the groups *before* ingestion

> Should I change the mapping of the field?

I'd say go for it. When you know which group you'll be targeting, you should, ideally, extract the groups *before* you ingest the documents.

See, what I'd do in your case is the following:

- Preserve the original `info_list` as a keyword for consistency
- Extract the groups in the programming language of your choice, annotate them with keys `a` to `i` (analogously to the way you naturally think about said groups).
- Store store them inside a [`nested` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in order to guarantee that the connections between the keys and the values aren't lost due to [array flattening](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects).

In concrete terms:

1. Set up a mapping

```json
PUT extracted-groups-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "info_list": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }, 
      "info_list_groups": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "group_key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Ingest the doc(s)

```json
POST extracted-groups-index/_doc
{
  "info_list": "1234 2D 5678 8765 5678 1111 2222 3333 1",
  "info_list_groups": [
    {
      "group_key": "a",
      "value": "1234"
    },
    {
      "group_key": "b",
      "value": "2D"
    },
    {
      "group_key": "c",
      "value": "5678"
    },
    { ... } // omitted for brevity
  ]
}
```

3. Leverage a pair of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) [`term` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html):

```json
POST extracted-groups-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "info_list_groups",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "info_list_groups.group_key": "c"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "info_list_groups.value": "5678"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Harnessing the full power of Elasticsearch

The downside of the `nested` approach is that it'll increase your index size. Plus, the queries tend to get quite verbose and confusing. If you don't want to go that route, you can leverage what's called a **custom analyzer**.

Such an analyzer is typically composed of:

- a [`tokenizer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) (which receives character streams and outputs a stream of tokens -- usually words)
- and a few [token `filters`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html) whose role it is to mold the tokens into the desired form.

In concrete terms, the aim here is to:

1. Take in the string `1234 2D 5678 8765 5678 1111 2222 3333 1` as a whole
2. Locate the individual groups separated by whitespace

   --> `(1234) (2D) (5678) (8765) (5678) (1111) (2222) (3333) (1)`
3. Annotate each group with its alphabetical index

   --> `a:1234 b:2D c:5678 d:8765 e:5678 f:1111 g:2222 h:3333 i:1`
4. And finally split the resulting string by whitespace in order to use queries like `a:1234` and `c:5678`

All of this can be achieved through a combination of the "noop" [`keyword` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html), and [`pattern_replace`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) + [`pattern_capture` filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html):

```json
PUT power-of-patterns
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "info_list": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "annotated_groups": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "info_list_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "info_list_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["pattern_grouper", "pattern_splitter"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "pattern_grouper": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "((?<a>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<b>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<c>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<d>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<e>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<f>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<g>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<h>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))((?<i>(?:\b ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0}.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?))",
          "replacement": "a:${a}b:${b}c:${c}d:${d}e:${e}f:${f}g:${g}h:${h}i:${i}"
        },
        "pattern_splitter": {
          "type" : "pattern_capture",
           "preserve_original" : true,
           "patterns" : [
              "([a-i]\\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
           ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that the [friendly-looking regex](https://regex101.com/r/EAAFPR/1) from above is nothing more than a repetitive [named group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415635/8160318) catcher.*

After setting up the mapping, you can ingest the document(s):

```json
POST power-of-patterns/_doc
{
  "info_list": [
    "1234 2D 5678 8765 5678 1111 2222 3333 1"
  ]
}
```

And then search for the desired segment in a nice, human-readable form:

```json
POST power-of-patterns/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "info_list.annotated_groups": "c:5678"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
"query" : "([^ ]+ ){2}5678( [^ ]){6}"
```

which is English is “two terms-with-a-space, then your search term, then 6 spaces-with-terms”

Comment: Interesting simplification. One remark: ES [doesn't support anchor operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-unsupported-operators). So only `([^ ]+ ){2}5678 .*` works.

Comment: @JoeSorocin OK (answer edited), but without the correct tail it will find the target elsewhere than 3rd position.